# can't connect to Tornado Websocket from web Application : Error 403

Tags: websocket, tornado

I have a web page should update its contents from a Python server using Tornado WebSocket.

1. I have built the web pages using PHP/MVC
2. It works perfectly with Local Apache (access the page with localhost)
3. Tornado Server runs successfully and process all income requests
4. I have added a pure JavaScript at the end of my page to open a WebSocket

**My Problem**

> Tornado Server reply with `304` and print (e.g:'Hello') **if and only if** the request comes from a direct access (I mean to send request manually, out of web page like: `192.168.8.103:8888`)
>
> When I try to open a WebSocket from the web page, Torando Server reply with `200` and fail to print the message (e.g:'Hello') as the attached images.

[image: Tornado error message (server-side)]

[image: Web page error message]

**Tornado Script (server):**

```python
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('Hello')
        #self.flush()
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("connected")
    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received %s' % message
        self.write_message('message received %s' % message)
    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(
        handlers=[
            (r"/", IndexHandler),
            (r"/ws", WebSocketHandler)
        ]
    )
    httpServer = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    httpServer.listen(options.port)
    print "Listening on port:", options.port
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

**WebSocket script (client):**

```js
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.8.103:8888/ws");
  socket.onopen = function(){  
    console.log("connected"); 
  }; 
  socket.onmessage = function (message) {
    console.log("receiving: " + message.data);
  };
  socket.onclose = function(){
    console.log("disconnected"); 
  };
  sendMessage = function(message) {
    socket.send(message);
  };
  try{
      var value = 0;
      window.onload = function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        console.log('Sending Value: ' + value);
      sendMessage("{sensor: Ultra, value:" + value + "}");
      value += 10;
      },10000)
  };
  } catch(err)
    {
    alert("Error with creating the WebSocket"+err)
    }
```

I've searching for a solution for three days with no result :( ... I'm grateful for any help, Many Thanks for everyone

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Your code works fine for me.

Comment: That's why I'm confused ... Nothing wrong in code ... but I want to know is why to receive the Error 200 and sometimes 304 with No output .. and Apache configurations are right and it can interpret my PHP page ... NO RESULT :(

Comment: Are you running your Tornado server behind a reverse proxy?

Comment: Mmm I think this is my problem, I'm grateful for your help @gre_gor ... could you please tell me how because I've tried to make a reverse proxy in apache config but when I did that I obtain 503 error and the web page couldn't be downloaded

Comment: Your reverse proxy problem should be question for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Ok thank you anyway 